# How to test Laravel Job with Delay?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-queue

I've a job that is being delayed with a dynamic value:

```php
SomeJob::dispatch()->delay($time);
```

In **PHPUnit**, we can test if a job has been dispatched or not, but is there any way to check if the job has been dispatched after that specific **$time**?

Comment: Any luck with my answer?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried that but it doesn’t make sure it will be dispatched at that specific moment. But good enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search turned up a number of articles on doing this. Call `Queue::fake()` and then assert that the job was placed on the queue. Within this assertion, you can confirm that it has a delay.

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Jobs\SomeJob;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testJobDelayed()
    {
        Queue::fake();

        // [...] Run code that dispatches the job

        // Assert that Job was pushed with a delay
        Queue::assertPushed(SomeJob::class, fn ($job) => !is_null($job->delay));
    }
}
```

Source: https://mauricius.dev/test-laravel-job-delayed-in-queue/